# jQuery XML Traversing

Tags: jquery

I have the following XML format and would like to get the list of markers for each category using jQuery.

```
<categories>
    <category id="1">
        <marker />
        <marker />
        <marker />
    </category>
    <category id="2">
        <marker />
        <marker />
        <marker />
    </category>
    <category id="3">
        <marker />
        <marker />
        <marker />
    </category>
</categories>
```

I am loading the XML correctly using jQuery with an AJAX call and when I use jQuery.find().each I am getting anywhere. Am I doing it wrong?

```
$(data).find('category[id=1] > marker').each(function() {}
$(data).find('categories category[id=1] > marker').each(function() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution would be correct, except that you're missing the closing `);`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/vyFeZ/

```
$(data).find('category[id=1] > marker').each(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Bingo! I was using $(data).find('category[id=1] > marker').each(function() {}); noticed that data was being called where it should not have and changing its position fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, I did go over all my scripting and placing the var data; should not have matter where it got placed but it did. I assuming it is being called from another script I am using that is encrypted and must have conflicted with mine. Changing it to another variable solved the issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

A sample from my code , replace the names with your code

// process your code inside the loops

```
 $(callback).find('CartClass Shipments Shipment Items Item').each(function() {                       
                        $(callback).find('EstimatedArrivalDate Item').each(function() {

});

                    });
```